# Putting an ID on <body> in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, view

I would like my views to be able to specify a class for the `<body>` tag, which lies in my master page.

My first take was to do something like this:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyClassContent" runat="server">
    view-item</asp:Content>
```

However, that would require this in the master page, which doesn't work:

```
<body class="<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BodyClassContent" runat="server" />">
```

Any solutions to this?

Comment: JavaScript in your view can do if you don't want ViewModel to hold this ;-)

Comment: Another crazy idea is to have custom ViewPage class with your BodyCss property; not sure if you can set it early enough, but that's just an idea. Honestly, just use ViewData/ViewModel and you're set ;-) Or custom view engine like Spark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach.

You create an hierachy of view models, starting with the MasterModel. When you instantiate a view object, you pass a body class to it.

```
public class MasterModel
{
    string BodyCss { get; set; }

    public MasterModel (string bodyCss)
    {
        BodyCss = bodyCss;
    }
}

public class MyView1Model : MasterModel
    : base ("body-view1")
{
}
```

Then in your master view which should be strongly typed to MasterView:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<MasterModel>" %>
```

you just write:

```
<body class="<%= Model.BodyCss %>"></body>
```

Comment: Good idea, but I would rather not have the class in my model – I want the view to solely responsible for layout, and thereby CSS.

Answer (score 7):

In the layout you can do this on the body tag:

```
<body @RenderSection("BodyAttributes", false)>
```

and then in your view you can do this:

```
@section BodyAttributes {
    id="login" class="login"
}
```

Edit: I also had to do this working with VB.NET and WebForms today and found a handy link for achieving the [equivalent](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19386/Adding-attributes-to-the-lt-body-tag-when-using-Ma)

Answer (score 5):

You could also specify the body id attribute in the View which wishes to set it:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Test";
ViewData["BodyID"] = "test";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}
```

This helps to decouple the view from the controller, the controller (and/or view model) does not need to know about the id attribute of the body tag.

Set the id of the body tag in the master page like so:

```
<body id="@ViewData["BodyID"]">
```

Comment: Good answer. The question was asked when MVC only came bundled with WebForms views - Razor makes this much nicer.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you do in your masterpage:

```
<body class="<%=ViewData["bodyClass"].toString()%>">
```

and then set ViewData["bodyClass"] in your Controller actions? That should be equivalent...